# Inequality for the sum of $q$th powers, $1<q<2$

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces

If $q$ is in $[1,2)$ and $a,b$ real numbers, is it always true that

$|a+b|^q + |a-b|^q \leq 2(|a|^q+|b|^q)$ ?

---

I can prove $|a+b|^q \leq 2^q (|a|^q + |b|^q)$ but this leaves me with an extra $2^q$ and I am not really sure how to better estimate the second term: $|a-b|^q$ or use the bound on $q$.

Comment: I can prove $|a+b|^q \leq 2^p (|a|^p + |b|^q)$ but this leaves me with an extra $2^p$ and I am not really sure how to better estimate the second term: $|a-b|^p$ or use the bound on $p$.

Comment: Is $p=q?$ If so, then you already have done $q=1.$

Comment: @polya : please include your efforts in the question itself and not just in a comment, so everyone will see it.  It is easy to edit your own questions.  In future questions, you should always include what you have proven yourself, even if it doesn't seem important to you.  You are more likely to get helpful answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

If either $a$ or $b$ is zero, the inequality is obviously an equality. So we need to consider only cases where both are non-zero.  WLOG, let $a \ge b > 0$ so that $x = \frac{b}{a} \in [0, 1]$.  Then it is sufficient to show:

$$(1+x)^q + (1-x)^q \leq 2(1+x^q)$$

From power means, we have for $q \le 2$: 
$$\sqrt[q]{\frac{(1+x)^q+(1-x)^q}{2}} \le \sqrt{\frac{(1+x)^2+(1-x)^2}{2}} = \sqrt{1+x^2}$$

$$\implies (1+x)^q+(1-x)^q \le 2(1+x^2)^{q/2}$$

So what remains is to show $(1+x^2)^{q/2} \le 1+x^q$ or equivalently to show that $f(r) = \sqrt[r]{1+x^r}$ is a decreasing function, which follows from the sign of $f'( r)$.